# Will be Dragon Age II on XBox 360 available to all console users?

Tags: xbox-360, dragon-age-2

I want to buy DA2 for X360 from Marketplace. I wonder if when I buy it on my user, can other console users play this game?

Notice, I **do not mean** playing **simultaneously** just if the game will be available to play to other users.

**Update:**

Not necessary a duplicate - I have various experiences depending on actual game, publisher, etc. I am looking for confirmed experiences with Dragon Age II bought digitally for Xbox 360.

Comment: Well according to my sources game was released 6 years ago...

Comment: So it was, nevermind me!

Comment: Hehe, I know it's an oldie - but I run out of all worthy RPGs for a moment and not going to go for X1 just yet :)

Comment: I simply jumped the gun, my bad.

Comment: No worries! I hope someone knows. Otherwise I just buy DVD version.